# HTTPS access to S3 bucket through Cloudflare

Tags: https, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I'm trying to use Cloudflare to provide https access to an s3 bucket. I've setup the CNAME entry in Cloudfront with pointing to the bucket and I've verified I can access it via http but when I try and access the contents with https, I get a 521 error saying the server i.e. bucket is unavailable.

Is it possible to front an s3 bucket with https through cloudflare or is it being blocked?

Comment: I think you mean you set up the CNAME in Cloudflare, not Cloudfront. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use Cloudflare with "Flexible SSL" or "Full SSL"?

For "Full SSL", this works for me:

- Try following this guide
  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-
- You should have an Amazon Bucket URL that is e.g.
  https://cdn.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com and you actually want https://cdn.example.com
- Do not attempt to do anything with the S3 static configuration or try to use the URLs, just leave that switched off
- The https link should give you an "Untrusted connection" error in the
  browser. Because with "Full SSL", Cloudflare doesn't validate the
  cert, you can set up a CNAME as described in the guide and have
  your SSL working fine in the browser then.

Of course with Full SSL on Cloudflare, using https for your actual website means you need a cert on your own server aswell.

Comment: From my testing this doesn't work. If you accept the the untrusted certain it will kind of work, though the SSL on the main website will gain a warning. If you don't accept the cert Chrome at least won't load the image.

Comment: Well, I have this live and running. You won't get a browser warning if Cloudflare is in front of it, and unless you do "Strict SSL" as they call it, the name mismatch between your CNAME vs. the domain in S3's cert will not matter.

Comment: With Full SSL and the default settings it won't work, so at best the answer needs to be updated to include instructing cloudflare to be lax about upstream SSL.

Comment: @webjunkie can you provide a link to your site where this is currently running?